# Loading CDI beans in different JARs with Payara 4.1.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, payara

we are currently porting our JEE 6 application (WAR deployment) from GF 3.1 to Payara 4.1.1. We are using EJBs and CDI beans. They are packaged in different jar files. I am facing the problem the CDI beans that are located in another jar file cannot be found. Each jar file has its own META-INF/beans.xml and there is also one for the WAR (WEB-INF/beans.xml) archive. I already tried the following steps:

- adopt beans.xml (bean-discovery-mode="all")
- deploy the WAR inside of and EAR deployment.
- changed annotations that changed with CDI 1.1
- updated all libraries to the latest version (richfaces, guava, eclipselink, ...) to meet the JEE 7 requirements

Does anybody know if there is general bug in Glassfish/Payara 4.1.1?

Thx,
Bernd

Unfortunately that did not help.  I did some more investigations and it seems like only "some" beans cannot be injected or retrieved from the BeanManager correctly. Here the class hierarchy that does not work:

```
`// AllwaysFalse is our own annotation.
@AllwaysFalse
@Named
public class AllwaysFalseRemoteCondition<E extends IStandardEntity>
         extends ConditionBase<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate, E>
         implements RemoteCondition<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate, E>      
{
…
}

// The abstract base class
public abstract class ConditionBase<R, T extends IStandardEntity> implements      Condition<R, T> {
}

// The base interface
public interface RemoteCondition<T, E extends IStandardEntity> extends  Condition<T, E> {
```

}

```
public interface Condition<T, E extends IStandardEntity> extends Part<ConditionDescriptor> {
…
}
```

If I change the class above to:

```
public class AllwaysFalseRemoteBotCondition<E extends IStandardEntity> {
}
```

The injection works.

If I try to inject the beans via the BeanManager the getBeans() method does not work if I do a type based search:

```
`BeanManager bm = getBeanManager();
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(clazz, annotations);
```

If I provide the interface class in the "class" parameter the return value is always null.

Comment: There's no bug that I know of. Are you getting any kind of error message(s) in the server.log? It would help to see those. What version of Payara are you using? The version scheme is last 2 digits of the year + quarter number. The lastest version is 161.1 (162 is due to be release in the coming days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(
    new TypeLiteral<RemoteCondition<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate,?>>() {}
    .getType(), 
    new AnnotationLiteral<AlwaysFalse>(){}
```

The TypeLiteral solved the problem! Thanks to Payara support!

Answer (score 0):

Download weld-servlet.jar and put into the library of your project, or better, why you are not using wildfly? He carry all jars to run cdi in your aplication.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.  I did some more investigations and it seems like only "some" beans cannot be injected or retrieved from the BeanManager correctly. Here the class hierarchy that does not work: